# Create MAPI profile for Exchange 2013 using MFCMAPI & MAPICDO

Tags: mapi, exchange-server-2013

I'm posting this in the hope it may help others.

We have been trying to create a MAPI email profile on a Windows 2008 R2 server to connect to Exchange 2013.

Most posts and links will take you to the home page of MFCMAPI which is a great resource. We followed the instructions but kept getting the following error when trying to connect:

```
Error:
Code: MAPI_E_LOGON_FAILED == 0x80040111
Function CallOpenMsgStore( lpMAPISession, (ULONG_PTR)m_hWnd, lpEntryID, ulFlags, (LPMDB*)lppMAPIProp)
File MainDlg.cpp
Line 435
```

What we found is that we didn't have the latest version of mapicdo. This was for two reasons.

1. The link on the mfcmapi blog was pointing to an old version (now fixed)
2. Google searches for mapicdo  will take you to the May 2013 update.

But there is another version dated **March 2014** which was released *after* Exchange 2013. Annoyingly both ms pages claim they are version 1.2.1. Look for march 2014 in the description.

The following link is for the March 2014 version.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42040

I will add more to this post so it can be used as a resource.

What i have learned along the way:
MAPI will not be supported beyond Exchange 2013 and really isn't 100% supported in 2013 either. The modern alternative is EWS.

So to put this in the form of a question: how do I create a mapi profile to connect to Exchange 2013?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you download the latest mapicdo. At time of writing this (2015-10-13) the last update was March 2014:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42040

Then you download mfcmapi

https://mfcmapi.codeplex.com

Then you follow the instructions on how to configure mapi for exchange 2013

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dvespa/archive/2013/05/21/how-to-mfcmapi-create-mapi-profile-exchange-2013.aspx

Edit: David V's blog is now pointing to the latest version of mapicdo.